# Transparent background becomes white on image resize

Tags: html, ios, css, background-image, background-blend-mode

I have an HTML page where I need to render 3 images, one on top of each other.

```
<div id="preview">
    <img src="transparent-image">
</div>
```

with the following CSS

```
#preview{
    background-image:url(layer0-image), url(layer1-image);
    background-size:100%, 100px;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    width: 820px;
    height: 350px;
}
```

The fist 2 images gets blended together using the CSS property background-blend-mode: multiply, on top of this I put the last image (transparent-image) with a transparent background (Imagine a photo of a room, with the wall area being transparent).

The result is exactly what I want but when I try to put

```
#preview{
    width:100%
}
```

to make it responsive; It works flawlessly, but on ios the transparency is lost.
I tested this behaviour on Chrome, Safari and Firefox (iOS). No problem at all on Chrome, Safari, Firefox on OSX, Android, Windows.

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks for your time.

**EDIT:**

layer0-image and transparent-image are the same image, layer0-image has no transparency and gets multiplied with layer1-image then on top of this blended image I put transparent-image.

I tried to change transparent-image with another one, the problem seems to be the blending between layer0-image and layer1-image, but due to the fact that layer0-image and transparent-image are the same, at first I thought there was a transparency problem.

The transparency is there, but the div #preview has 0px height when put to

```
#preview{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Showing no blending.

**EDIT2**:

I'm adding an example to show and replicate the error: https://jsfiddle.net/dyqnghdo/3/

Comment: You must set transparency with WebKit.

Comment: the transparent-image is a PNG with transparency.

Comment: Hmm... It works on OSX and on mobile safari not? I don't understand it. Interesting question.

Comment: Exactly, works fine on Safari (but even on Chrome, Firefox) using OSX and on Chrome and Firefox on Android.When I test it on iOS what I see is the image transparent-image with no transparency, losing the effect of seeing through the wal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found the problem. Having:

```
#preview{
    background-image:url(layer0-image), url(layer1-image);
    background-size:100%, 100px;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    width: 820px;
    height: 350px;
}
```

and then setting:

```
#preview{
    width:100%;
}
```

casused the error. To fix it I tried setting:

```
#preview{
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover, 100px;
}
```

The problem is gone even if it's not clear to me why it was happening.